# Upsides of using ^ as default save-prefix

Tags: javascript, npm

In my perception, using circumflex (^) for `npm install` per default is not really pragmatic.

If all the packages are upgraded to the latest minors on `npm update` without further notice, this can lead to the utter destruction of the entire product in many cases.

I'd understand default updates for patch versions (~) as they are, by the semver definition, important bug/security-fixes.

So what are the upsides of defaulting to circumflex on `npm install package-name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"minor" updates shouldn't harm Backward compatibility by definition.
I guess that's why adding the "^" prefix is mostly seen as a benefit, you just get some fixes, minor features and so on without having to worry.

I had situations where that prefix caused some problems, but they were mostly related to conflicts in the .lock file after builds and so on

Answer (score 2):

Per semver definition minor versions should **not** contain breaking changes. Only major versions should contain breaking changes.

You can go by this definition:

Major - Breaking recode of package
Minor - New feature / bigger changes - non breaking
Patch - Bugfixes / smaller changes - non breaking